# $http.get(Routing.generate(my_route_to_json))

Tags: angularjs, json, symfony

I am trying to fetch data from database from inside the symfony controller and encode the response to json format, here:

```
/**
 * @Route("/jsondata", options={"expose"=true}, name="my_route_to_json_data")
 */
public function tagsAction(Request $request)
{        
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
       'SELECT t.text
       FROM AppBundle:Tag t
       WHERE t.id > :id
       ORDER BY t.id ASC'
       )->setParameter('id', '0');

    $tagsdata = $query->getScalarResult();
    $response = new Response(json_encode($tagsdata));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
}
```

Here is the json response:
[image]

Now in my angularJS code I am trying to load this json data by using `Routing.generate()` of the FOSjsrouting Bundle. Here :

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.loadTags = function(query){
    return $http.get(Routing.generate('my_route_to_json_data'));
        };
    });
```

Here is the index.html.twig :

```
{% verbatim %}
    <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <tags-input ng-model="tags" add-on-paste="true">
            <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
        </tags-input>
    <p>Model: {{tags}}</p>
    </body>
    {% endverbatim %}
```

Everything works fine, except the auto complete doesn't work. 
Funny part is the same code in text file works like a charm :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/css/ng-tags-input.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/js/ng-tags-input.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

      app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {         
        $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
          return $http.get('tags.json');
        };
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <tags-input ng-model="tags" add-on-paste="true">
      <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
    </tags-input>
    <p>Model: {{tags}}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

tags.json :

```
[
  { "text": "Tag1" },
  { "text": "Tag2" },
  { "text": "Tag3" },
  { "text": "Tag4" },
  { "text": "Tag5" },
  { "text": "Tag6" },
  { "text": "Tag7" },
  { "text": "Tag8" },
  { "text": "Tag9" },
  { "text": "Tag10" }
]
```

I am new to AngularJS, any ideas how do I deal with this?
If anything, please lemme know while debugging what to look for and how to check if the json data is getting loaded.
Thanks in advance.

Here is a screenshot of the console:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Routing.generate('url')` is a module to `FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle`

before install [fosJSroutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)
and for fetch data try this :

```
      app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {                
          $http.get('tags.json').success(function(result){
              $scope.loadTags = result
          );
      });
```

Comment: But I need `Routing.generate('url')`, where I replace url by `my_route_to_json_controller`

Comment: I am querying database and returning data from inside the controller with route name= `my_route_to_json_controller` . Then I encode the returned data inside the controller into json format by using `json_encode()`, before returning it as response object

Comment: you can simply use in your controller symphony

`return new JsonResponse(your array data);`

Comment: as you can see in my controller code at the top, I am using `$response = new Response(json_encode($tagsdata));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;` to turn my array data ie. `$tagsdata` into json response. The alternative u gave ie. `return new JsonResponse(your array data);` , does the same thing as far as I can tell. Although I tried that as well. However in the Angular code when I use `return $http.get(Routing.generate('my_route_to_json_data')).success(function(result){ $scope.loadTags = result;` , it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need bind the json result with the tags.

```
$http.get("tags.json")
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.tags = response.data;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Ahha! xD
Finally, this approach worked:

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
      return $http.get('http://localhost/AngularTags/web/js/tags.json');
       };
    });
```

Note: 
In this approach i saved my server data inside tags.json and then loaded it. I used `http://localhost/AngularTags/web/js/tags.json` as the parameter to $http.get().

However for future usage I need to figure out how can I use Routing.generate() of the FOSjsRouting Bundle.